# Need help re-sizing and vertically centering font in a button when window width is gradually decreased

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I have a button which has some text in it. The way the button is currently set-up is that when the window width is decreased the vertical height of the button also decreases based on the window width. When I re-size the width gradually I want the text inside the button to also gradually decrease while at the same time always remaining vertically in the middle of the button. I currently cant figure out how to get this to work. As of now when I re-size the the window width and the vertical height decreases, the text remains large and not vertically centered.

I could use media queries, but this would require me to create numerous media queries for different widths.

I have tried numerous things to try to get this implemented but I cant seem to get it to work. I would really appreciate it if someone could show me a template of a css class that would provide this functionality.

This is css class I am currently using for the button:

```
.buttonClass{
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 3em !important;
    height: 12.5%;
    width: 25%;
    bottom: 1%;
    right: 0.25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using a viewport width for your font-size:

```
.buttonClass {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2vw;
    line-height: 3em;
    height: 12.5%;
    width: 25%;
    bottom: 1%;
    right: 0.25%;
}
```

For reference, 1vh = .01 * viewport height. Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/00gtL5ec/). Hope this helps.

Comment: The text will get pretty small on mobile devices, so you may want to add a  media query breakpoint or two to adjust the font-size (e.g. use font-size: 3vh at max-width: 480px or something similar)